# How to change `nifi.properties` file location from `/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/` to some other location

Tags: kubernetes, apache-nifi

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm trying to run nifi as a single pod statefulset in kubernetes with persistent volume attached to `/mnt/` and a few config maps mounted in this `/mnt/`

**What I have tried:**

1. I created `nifi.properties` as a config map and when I'm mounting in `mountPath` or `subPath` but mounting like this replacing all the other files present in the `/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/` and Pod is not able to start.
   How I'm mounting the nifi.properties:

```
        - name: nifi-properties
          mountPath: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
          subPath: nifi.properties
      volumes:
      - name: nifi-properties
        configMap:
          name: nifi-properties
```

When starting the nifi pod it gives me the following error.

```
File [/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties] replacing [nifi.web.https.port]
sed: cannot rename /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/sedROXqjT: Device or resource busy
```

But, if I'm mounting `zookeeper.properties` the same way as above. The pod can start without any errors.

2. I used this `env` `NIFI_PROPERTIES_FILE=/mnt/nifi.properties` in my pod.

**What I need:**

1. To know how to tell nifi to read the `nifi.properties` file from a different location.
2. To know the right way to persist all the stateful data of nifi.
3. To mount few of the config files (present in the conf/) in the `/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/` without overwriting the other default configs.

If possible share with me some good articles/videos/courses on how to migrate nifi to k8s or getting started with nifi on kubernetes.